# How to embedded or mock kafka in Spring multi module project Integration Tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Dears, I need to add some integration tests to many resources in a project we are working that uses Kafka but so far I was not able to have just one instance of Embedded Kafka running on all tests execution or to mock the entire Kafka part to focus tests just on our code, trusting that the integration will be fine.

So I have some questions:

1. What is the correct/preferable way to set those tests? To mock the Kafka part or to Embed an instance?
2. How can I embed it and share this instance between all tests to avoid instance being dropped and recreate without need?
3. How to mock all kafka part simulating it is working fine? So I can focus the test on our code and not in those other aspects?

Thank you very much.

---

What I have already tried:

- Annotate tests that need kafka with @EmbeddedKafka - it works but generates random error because in some cases the instance is dropped and it results in some FileNotFound to other instances
- Create a class with the @EmbeddedKafka and making tests that uses kafka extends from this class - result is similar to the approach above
- Trying to mock KafkaClient - still missing some bean or detail - resulting in:

  > Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
  >   Failed to start bean
  >   'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry';
  >   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No group.id found
  >   in consumer config, container properties, or @KafkaListener
  >   annotation; a group.id is required when group management is used.

---

Other details:

- Junit 5
- Gradle

Comment: Have you tried [this technique](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/#using-the-same-brokers-for-multiple-test-classes)? I am not aware of any such issues. If you can post a simple project that exhibits the behavior we can take a look.

Comment: Am also facing this same issue, any one know the answer?

Comment: If you are using docker, definitely have a look at [testcontainrs library](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/). I haven't tried them with Kafka yet, but for various databases works perfectly fine. 
Similarly you can just [spin-up local Kafka with this docker image](https://github.com/lensesio/fast-data-dev) and manage it yourself.